# SQLite query failing but only when offline

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I have a simple SQLite method which returns a class given two parameters - the type T and the parameter value to be searched

```
public T GetSingleObject<T>(string id) where T:IIdentity, new()
    {
        lock (dbLock)
        {
            using (var sqlCon = new SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
            {
                sqlCon.Execute(Constants.DBClauseSyncOff);
                sqlCon.BeginTransaction();
                string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE id=\"{1}\"", GetName(typeof(T).ToString()), id);
                var data = sqlCon.Query<T>(sql);
                return data[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have another method that takes 3 parameters, T, the parameter to be seated and the value to search for

```
public T GetSingleObject<T>(string para, string val) where T:IIdentity, new()
    {
        lock (dbLock)
        {
            using (var sqlCon = new SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
            {
                sqlCon.Execute(Constants.DBClauseSyncOff);
                sqlCon.BeginTransaction();
                string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}=\"{2}\"", GetName(typeof(T).ToString()), para, val);
                var data = sqlCon.Query<T>(sql).FirstOrDefault();
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
```

These methods work without an issue and return the values expected, but with one caveat - there is a single table which works fine when the phone has a connection, but not when it's in aeroplane mode. The table has nothing more in it than strings, doubles, ints, DateTime and bool values.

GetName is a simple method that removes the assembly bits and pieces and leave just the classname

```
 private string GetName(string name)
    {
        var list = name.Split('.').ToList();
        if (list.Count == 1)
            return list[0];
        var last = list[list.Count - 1];
        return last;
    }
```

I have tried every way I can think of to access this table - including a straight

```
sqlCon.ExecuteScalar<MyClass>("SELECT * FROM MyClass");
```

and nothing offline, perfect data online.

The class itself looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SQLite;

namespace Models
{
public class MyClass : IIdentity
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string home_id { get; set; }

    public string username { get; set; }

    public string password { get; set; }

    public string firstname { get; set; }

    public string lastname { get; set; }

    public string email { get; set; }

    public bool syncenabled { get; set; }

    public string tradingname { get; set; }

    public string address { get; set; }

    public string town { get; set; }

    public string state { get; set; }

    public string country { get; set; }

    public string securitystamp { get; set; }

    public string password_question { get; set; }

    public string password_answer { get; set; }

    public string mobileServiceAuthenticationToken { get; set; }

    public string providerUserKey { get; set; }

    public string mobiledeviceid { get; set; }

    public DateTime last_login { get; set; }

    public DateTime __createdAt { get; set; }

    public DateTime __updatedAt { get; set; }

    public string user_type { get; set; }

    public bool is_deleted { get; set; }

    public bool account_enabled { get; set; }

    public string subscription_id { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember, Ignore]
    public List<MyUsers> UserModules { get { return AppDelegate.Self.DBManager.GetListOfObjects<MyUsers>("user_id", id); } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[MyClasss: id={0}, home_id={1}, username={2}, password={3}, firstname={4}, lastname={5}, email={6}, syncenabled={7}, tradingname={8}, address={9}, town={10}, state={11}, country={12}, securitystamp={13}, password_question={14}, password_answer={15}, mobileServiceAuthenticationToken={16}, providerUserKey={17}, mobiledeviceid={18}, last_login={19}, __createdAt={20}, __updatedAt={21}, user_type={22}, is_deleted={23}, account_enabled={24}, subscription_id={25}, UserModules={26}]", id, home_id, username, password, firstname, lastname, email, syncenabled, tradingname, address, town, state, country, securitystamp, password_question, password_answer, mobileServiceAuthenticationToken, providerUserKey, mobiledeviceid, last_login, __createdAt, __updatedAt, user_type, is_deleted, account_enabled, subscription_id, UserModules);
    }
}
```

Nothing in there that I can see should cause an issue when offline. The query always returns null offline, data online.

Comment: Side note: That code scream SQL injection.  Change it to use parameters.

Comment: Where is your database file located? I assume locally. So I don't think the error you're facing is related to the connection status of your device.

Comment: I've checked the connection of the database and that works fine, every other table works fine and returns values, but this one always returns null.

Comment: ctacke - I've got SQL protection code elsewhere :)